# Cake PHP hiding/showing form elements based on dropdown selection

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, cakephp

How can I show and hide form elements in CakePHP based on a dropdown selection:

Outside of CakePHP, I would usually use jquery or ajax but I cant seem to find anything that tells you how to do this with this scenario in CakePHP.

Here is what I have in the view:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Spec'); ?>
<fieldset>
    <legend><?php echo __('Add Spec'); ?></legend>
<?php
    echo $this->Form->input('ref');
    echo $this->Form->input('service_id',array('empty'=>'Please Select'));

    echo $this->Form->input('a1',array(
                                                        'label' => 'Background:',
                                                        'div' => false
                                                    ));
    echo $this->Form->input('a2',array(
                                                        'label' => 'Business objectives:',
                                                        'div' => false
                                                    ));
```

When I select a 'service', dependent on my selection I need to either show or hide a1 and a2.

Comment: are you insistent on using cake-php for this.???

Comment: well its just this project is built using the CakePHP framework and I don't have the time to completely start again.

Comment: so u can't perform this by jquery..??

Comment: Well I guess I could put jquery into the view, but I didn't know if Cake has something already built that would work in this scenario that I should make use of.

Comment: CakePHP has a JS helper, but you're better off just doing your own jquery/javascript code.

Comment: I'll do that. Thanks for the advice Outlooker & @Nebojsac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with CakePHP, and Cake is not preventing you from doing this as you normally would.  All you're doing with Cake here is using the HTML helpers to output the HTML for your form using PHP.

Once the page has loaded, your form is there with all the HTML generated, so you are in exactly the same situation as you would be having built any other non-Cake webpage using HTML. You can use jQuery combined with CSS as normal to hide/show the select boxes as the user interacts with them.

Load jQuery in your Layout file, and add your individual script for this page at the bottom of the view, or also in your Layout file if you like. Really, CakePHP is just the framework to make generating your page easier, but it's all server-side code, so once the user has requested the page and it is loaded by the client, CakePHP has done its job and effectively plays no further part in what you do with your page with regard to client-side interactivity.